# ShieldUi manipulating chart as soon as it is rendered

Tags: image, charts, wicket, shieldui

I'm facing shieldUI wicket integration and I'm trying to get base 64 image dfom a shieldUi chart using this tutorial: https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/javascript.chart/exporting

I tried to run the code below:

```js
function render_image_box(chart_id) {
 var result = false;
 var svg_chart = $("#" + chart_id);
 if (svg_chart) {
  var chart = svg_chart.swidget();
  if (chart != null) {
   chart.exportToImage();
   result = true;
  }
 }
 // setTimeout(find_image_source, 100) // wait before continuing
 return chart;
}
```

in both the `$(document).ready(..)` and  `$(window).load(...)` functions and the load event raised from the library (https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/javascript.chart/events/load) as well.

In none of these function chart is rendered yet, so the `svg_chart.swidget()` returns null.

Is there any other event to use to accomplish my goal or any other way to get the image source?

Thanks in advance,
Laura

Answer (score 0):

You can access the chart instance using `.swidget()` only after you have initialized it with the `.shieldChart()` constructor.

To make your code work, you should also turn off animation for the chart, because right after you initialize it, the rendering will not be over and there will be no image contents.

[Here is a complete JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xametasoci/edit?html,output) to get you started...

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for your answer but it didn't work in my scenario since:

 1. applyAnimation does not work in apache wicket integration. 
 2. I suppose .shieldChart() is called before load event is raised.

Can you provide any other suggestion?

Laura

Comment: Hi - for (1) - you can set applyAnimation on the seriesSettings, like in this updated example: http://jsbin.com/tokorufufi/edit?html,output

Comment: As for (2) - what do you mean? the .shieldChart() is the chart's constructor that initializes the chart. It is not possible to do anything with the chart before that has been called... And you have to call it after your document and jQuery have been fully loaded.

Comment: Hi, thanks for (1) solution. For (2) I mean that the chart is crated using apache wicket integration so it is inited in the java code.

Comment: You are right - the shieldui-wicket library will enclose the generated JS code in the proper jQuery(function($) { ... }); call, so it is initialized at the right time. I updated the example again - http://jsbin.com/tokorufufi/edit?html,console,output - to use the chart's "load" event and call a JS function - see if you can do it with Wicket...

Comment: Hi, I see the image box empty! I need the image box with the chart!

Comment: I see a blank box in both firefox and chrome.

Comment: Can you post your complete code, so we can see what you have?

Comment: I see a black box in your jsbin!